# Git clone permission denied

Tags: git, openshift, cloud9-ide

Trying out the new cloud9ide and I managed to get RHC installed for openshift and went through the setup uploaded the ssh key. I'm now trying to git clone my project but I'm getting permission errors.

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: What command are you running? It looks like you don't have permission or it can't find the repository

Comment: I have tried using both sudo git clone <git address> <folder> and sudo rhc git-clone <openshift domain> and both fail. I can use all the other commands with RHC though and on the openshift settings I can see the ssh key listed so I'm not sure why I'm getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to turn on username/password authentication in git. Edit your ~/.gitconfig (e.g., with nano), and remove the line that says "askpass = /bin/echo".

Comment: I'll give it a try. I was reading around and supposedly having an encrypted home folder may be the cause.